# How to add existing .Net core code to a new solution

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to reorganize my code and project structure to be microservice-like.
I created a new .sln file, and would like to add an existing .NET core 1.0 folder (that is a class library for an AWS Lambda function) to it.  I don't understand why there isn't a .csproj file to add in the core project.  Thus, how do I add it to the solution?

Comment: Did you try dotnet sln add command? ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln )

Comment: If there `project.json` file then you need migrate it to `csproj` file

Comment: @YpislonIV - where do I run this command? Nuget Package manger console? Dos Command line?  I don't get the concept.

Comment: Ok, looks like I just need to add existing project then select the .xproj file.  I have no idea what that is yet, and why there is no .cproj file, because I'm dealing with the transition from classic to core.

Comment: At this point I'm starting over, just building a new solution, add new Lambda project, then I will copy/paste code or files in, and try not to use core class library.